# Redirecting base URL to main URL in confluence?

Tags: confluence

I have upgraded my Confluence version from 6.3.3 to 6.5.1. Now when I try to hit the main URL, i.e. http://www.wedev.xyz.com then it shows Error 404, but when I hit the base URL http://www.wedev.xyz.com/wiki then all goes correct and the website opens.

So how to redirect the main URL to the base URL ?

Comment: Do you have context path configured in your server.xml file?

Comment: Yes the path is configured